# A uniqueness problem to ODE (Picard-Lindelöf or Cauchy-Lipschitz)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading a book says that the ODE
$$f'' + \frac{1}{x}f' +cf =0$$
has unique solution by Picard-Lindelöf or Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem given $f(0)=1, f'(0) =0.$

I tried to rewrite this as a first order ODE by defining:
$$g = \begin{bmatrix}
f'\\
f
\end{bmatrix} \quad A= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{x} &c\\
1 &0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then I have $$g' = Ag$$

But I found that $A$ is not bounded, so how can one apply the uniqueness theorem to this ODE? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bounded, but it is continuous and  locally Lipschitz with respect to $g$ in the complement of $\{0\}$, and that's all you need for local existence and uniqueness.  Of course the equation isn't defined at $x=0$, so you don't expect anything in a domain that includes $0$.

Actually, since the equation is linear, you have not just local but global existence and uniqueness in $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,0)$.